# Creating dataframe in a loop with custom name from a list of string in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dynamic, apache-spark-sql

Hey I have a typical requirement where I have to create dataframes in a loop with custom name from a list of string in scala.

Like i have a list of string say (Product, Customer, Order,......) and this list can have n number of items where n can be any number say till 30. Also the columns for each items in list are specified in another file.

So for each item in list like for example Product I have to create dataframe name as Product and later on I need to write spark SQL joining all the items in that list like below.

Select product.name, customer.name, order.Name 
From Product join customer ... join Order ...

And this join query will be dynamic based on the number of items in the list. I am thinking to create .scala file from a shell script. Let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL can be created from a Scala Object too. Based on the user input create an RDD first.
Then Create a List of Intended Objects based on your requirement and Create a Map of your Dataframe and Object Name. Then generate the SQL String using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have achieved this by creating a method called generateDF like below. This is taking a file list as a string("," separated) and a file with schema definition(",") separated and lastly a file that will contain the data.

```
def generateDF(fName: String, schemaFile: String, dataFile: String): Unit = {
// Reading the prod files and creating DataFrame from user defined schema
val SchemaRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(schemaFile)
val SchemaString = SchemaRDD.map(_.toString).collect().mkString
val Schema = StructType(SchemaString.split(",").map(column => StructField(column.split(":")(0), inferType(column), true)))
val outDF = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",").option("quote", "")
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(Schema)
  .load(dataFile)
outDF.createTempView(fName)
```

}

// calling the procedure for each table name in the source file

```
fileListRDD
      .flatMap(_.split(",")).collect.toList
      .map(file => generateDF(file.mkString.toString, (filePath + file.mkString + ".schema"), (filePath + file.mkString + ".csv")))
```

Comment: For dynamic SQL we can use a StringBuilder object and append with loop/Map function